# In the Injekt library for Kotlin, how do I create local scopes such as for each Android activity?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, kohesive-injekt

In the Injekt documentation on Github, it says that scopes exist but it isn't clear how I can use them to create a local scope for each Android activity, that have their own factories and instances but can also use some from a parent scope.

The `Injekt` variable appears to be a global scope, and I see `InjektScope` and `InjektScopeMain` but no examples of how to use them, or how they link to parent scopes.  The only way I see is to create separate `InjektScope` instances and call them, OR call `Injekt` as a global scope.  This works, but is clumsy.

No obvious way to link, nest, delegate or inherit.

Is this supported, and if so how?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Injekt + Kotlin topics are present in SO.  Other answers are also welcome, there are other styles of how to do this!  Disclosure, I am the author of the Injekt library.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** *This is now documented in the [Injekt README](https://github.com/kohesive/injekt/blob/master/README.md#scopes)*

It is supported by delegating factories between scopes.  First, some background:

Injekt allows manual scoping of instances into separate Injekt registries.  The global registry, available through the `Injekt` variable is just one scope that is pre-created for you.  You can also create new ones:

```
val myLocalScope: InjektScope = InjektScope(DefaultRegistrar())
```

This makes a standalone scope that has no relationship to the global or to others.

But then you can link scopes by creating factories in the new scope that delegate some of the instance creation to another scope.  For example the `myLocalScope` mentioned above could delegate some of the factories to `Injekt` global scope:

```
// delegate some factories to global Injekt instance
myLocalScope.addSingletonFactory { Injekt.get<SomeSingletonClass>() }
myLocalScope.addFactory { Injekt.get<SomeMultiValueClass>() }
```

When delegating factories such as this, any multi-value instances will not be cached by any scope since those factories create new instances on every call.  For singletons and keyed factories the objects are cached and a reference to those objects will exist in both the local and delegated scopes for any instances requested during its lifecycle.

You can also just use multiple scopes independently without linking or delegation.  Fetch some instances from a local scope, others from the global.  But you must use each scope independently and be careful of accidentally using the `Injekt` global variable when not intended.

If you have common factories needed in local scopes, you can easily create a descendent of `InjektScope` that registers these during its construction.

```
class MyActivityScope: InjektScope(DefaultRegistrar()) {
    init {
        // override with local value
        addSingletonFactory { SomeSingletonClass() }
        // import other registrations from defined modules
        importModule(OtherModuleWithPrepackagedInjektions)
        // delegate to global scope:
        addSingletonFactory { Injekt.get<SomeOtherSingleton>() }
    }
}

// then in each place you want a local scope
val localScope = MyActivityScope()

// later use the scope
val singly: SomeSingletonClass = localScope.get()
val other: SomeOtherSingleton = localScope.get()
```

Or using the same model as `InjektMain` create a descendent of `InjektScopedMain` that overrides function `fun InjektRegistrar.registerInjectables() { ... }`, if you prefer to be consistent with modules. For example:

```
class MyActivityModule: InjektScopedMain(InjektScope(DefaultRegistrar())) {
    override fun InjektRegistrar.registerInjectables() {
        // override with local value
        addSingletonFactory { NotLazy("Freddy") }
        // import other registrations from defined modules
        importModule(OtherModuleWithPrepackagedInjektions)
        // delegate to global scope:
        addSingletonFactory { Injekt.get<SomeOtherSingleton>() }
    }
}

// then in each place you want a local scope
val localScope = MyActivityModule().scope
```

And you can still use delegated properties, as long as the scope is declared before use in the delegate:

```
val myProp: SomeClass by localScope.injectValue()
```

You can use the `LocalScoped` base class to have local versions of `injectValue()` and `injectLazy()` to make it more convenient when injecting members (see [code for `LocalScoped`](https://github.com/kohesive/injekt/blob/master/api/src/main/kotlin/uy/kohesive/injekt/api/Scope.kt#L61-L79)).  This way your syntax stays consistent (see [example in tests](https://github.com/kohesive/injekt/blob/master/core/src/test/kotlin/uy/kohesive/injekt/TestInjektion.kt#L202-L247)).

To clear a local scope, drop your reference to the scope and it will garabage collect away.  There is no explicit clear method.

For more advanced, and more automatic scope linking / delegation / inheritance, please see [Injekt Github Issue #31](https://github.com/kohesive/injekt/issues/31) and provide comments on this possible future feature.

For the use case of having other classes inherit the same local scope when they are injected into the class declaring the local scope, see [Injekt Github Issue #32](https://github.com/kohesive/injekt/issues/32)

Comment: Note:  `LocalScoped` and the test example are in upcoming release `1.13.0` although their equivalent code would work in current release.  `1.3.0-RC-1050` is available on bintray repo `http://dl.bintray.com/jaysonminard/kohesive` and requires Kotlin EAP RC 1050.  A release to Maven Central will happen with that RC is no longer EAP.